# Understand Node 14 and async functions

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm having a little trouble understanding async with Node, I understand how to they work but every now and then I run into these problems that take up a lot of time when trying to soft out.

This function does nothing that I can see happening, is does not console log and does not write the file.

```
const { writeFile } = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const asyncWriteFile = promisify(writeFile);


const writeTxtFile = async () => {
  console.log("starting file write");
  let files = ["fileone", "filetwo"];
  try {
    await asyncWriteFile("fileList.txt", "hello", (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("There was an error with writeFile", err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("file written!");
      return true;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//calling with 
  writeTxtFile().then((status) => {
  console.log("status for write: ", status);
});
```

Then if I make a small change by changing the piece of code

```
await asyncWriteFile("fileList.txt", "hello", (err) => {

//change to
let res = await asyncWriteFile("fileList.txt", "hello", (err) => {
```

It creates the file correctly, however, I still don't get any console logs from the function or the call part.

I'm not sure where I'm going wring wuth all this.

Comment: I guess you are mixing up promises and callbacks and thats causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just promisify a function from `fs` and expect it to work. You might want to look into `fs.promises` for that.

Now even if that were to work, you are using an `await` in `asyncWriteFile`. `await` will wait for a the function to complete its execution which returns a promise, unlike callbacks, which expect a function to run after it completes execution, using a callback handler there won't cause it to be executed. Here is a version of `fs.promises.writeFile` that you might want to try.

```
const { writeFile } = require("fs").promises;

const writeTxtFile = async () => {
  console.log("starting file write");
  try {
    await writeFile("fileList.txt", "hello");
    console.log("file written!");
    return "Written!";
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("There was an error with writeFile", error);
    return "Not written!";
  }
};

//calling with 
  writeTxtFile().then((status) => {
  console.log("status for write: ", status);
});
```

Output

```
starting file write
file written!
status for write:  Written!
```

And yes file is indeed written.